# I cannot change my screen resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution

I just installed Ubuntu on an old Samsung desktop and the screen resolution is garbage. I cannot change it. I'm still pretty new to Ubuntu.

[image: bad screen resolution]

Answer (score 0):

### Screen Display

To change screen resolution in Ubuntu, go to Settings/Screen Display. You will find a drop down to adjust Resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings » Screen Display.

Make sure your display is at 1920x1080, turn fractional scaling off, turn scale to 100% as opposed to 200 and that should do it

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!